# How can i track the android phone operations internally?

Tags: android, api, internal, operations, tracker

I want to develop a mobile app that stores all user operations like clicking, selecting, swiping, and closing apps into a database. I have to store the button name, id and time of the operation.

How can I track that in Android without disturbing other apps that are running?

Comment: You may not have found a solution for the whole problem, but what have you found so far? Where have you looked?

Comment: I searched like is there any api to track the android phone operations. But i can't get.

Comment: A quick look around the Android SDK found me the [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) and [InputEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputEvent.html) classes - these may be a good place to start - but your question is very broad at the moment. If you can make it more specific, people will be able to give you more specific help.

Comment: ya. But my target is if you ware my app and that will track the all operations in the phone . For suppose if you open fb messenger that can track and store the details in the sqlite. After that you opened the playmusic app that details also store the app. In that play music app you clicked one song to play that details also i will store that database. I want this type app. I think you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way of doing this, because exposing an (easy) API to do this would allow way too many people to easily track their users' actions, including the passwords they type on their (virtual) keyboard, so this poses a real security issue. Assuming the app you develop has this tracking as its main purpose (and not as background "additional" non-advertised tracking), this is less of a concern.

It is possible to capture *some* events without interfering with other Activities by using an overlay. In your `Service`, where you create your capture window, specify it as a `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` with `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH`:

```
mView = new TouchCaptureView(this);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(mView, params);
```

Then override your touch capture View's `onTouchEvent` to record every `MotionEvent` in your database.
This however, does not allow you to know what the user actually clicked on, it could be a button, checkbox, etc, and there is **no** way of knowing that (plus the controls may be a custom implementation). Determining the resulting action is just plain impossible to do, as apps doesn't broadcast their users' actions to other apps.
Also, beginning with Android 4.0, overlay windows don't capture events anymore, `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` still does but interferes with other Activities.

**TL;DR: you can't .**

Comment: [The list of permissions an app can request](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) should give you an indication of what is possible. As gravgun points out, listening for events in other apps does not seem to be one of those, for very valid security reasons.